# iOS - PHP Match UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encoding, hash

I am playing around with signatures for request on the iPhone.
I have a simple PHP script running that will verify incoming JSON data against the signature in the header (all in all it is very similar to two-legged OAuth).

The following Obj-C code generates the signature:

```
const char *cKey = [kConsumerSecret cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *cData = [payload cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Payload: %s", cData);

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
NSData *hmac = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
NSString *signature = [hmac base64EncodedString];
```

And the verifying PHP code looks like this:

```
$originalPayload = '{"name":"Ben’s iPhone"}'; // The message received from iOS
$hash = hash_hmac("sha256", $originalPayload, "Secret Key", TRUE);
$signature = strtr(base64_encode($hash), array('=' => '', '+' => '-', '/' => '_'));
```

The functions work perfectly fine when using ASCII characters. But when they contain UTF-8 characteres iOS calculates the signature based on:

```
Ben‚Äôs iPhone
```

While PHP calculates it based on:

```
Ben\u2019s iPhone
```

Making the signatures invalid. I have tried multiple approaches and none of them have yielded any results. Does anyone have an idea for how to solve this issue?

Remark: Yes, I could simply use OAuth, but I'm just curious on how to implement it myself.

**Update:** I have tracked down the problem to a part in the code, that modifies the parsed JSON array in the PHP code. In order to hash, but not include it in the body, I added the temporary index 'time' that contained a UTC timestamp. That modification of the original array made PHP change the character representation (escaping UTF-8 characters). Just appending the timestamp work fine.

Nonetheless the functions should yield the same result, shouldn't they?